# TFS everywhere issue

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I mapped from tfs source to my local PC, and open the source with eclipse, I found that the source are not connected to the TFS server. I try to reconnect the source to TFS server, right click on the project, only two choses: "Apply Patch"and "Share Porject",I chosed the "Share Project" and shows me the repository type selection panel,
I select the Team Foundation Server, it tells me that like "No D:\project\framework\repo" working folder mapping.

any one can tell me why, I have been stucked by this problem for hours and googled, find no useful information
[image]

Comment: Um~~ solved ths issue. Thanks anyway

Comment: If you've solved it please post the solution to share with others.